# Silverlight 4.0 FileStream

Tags: silverlight, filestream

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

> Arguments: << path >> Debugging resource
>   strings are unavailable. Often the key
>   and arguments provide sufficient
>   information to diagnose the problem.
>   See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.41108.0&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=FileSecurityState_OperationNotPermitted

The line of code above has an error [FileSecurityState_OperationNotPermitted]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your application is running in partial trust.  To use a FileStream, you'll need to request [elevated trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28VS.96%29.aspx):

> By default, Silverlight-based
>   applications run in partial trust,
>   which means they run within a security
>   sandbox. Sandboxed applications have
>   restricted access to the local
>   computer and are constrained in other
>   ways that help prevent malicious
>   behavior.

From the Silverlight 4 FileStream documentation (emphasis mine):

> **When it is called by an elevated-trust
>   application**, exposes a Stream  around
>   a file, supporting both synchronous
>   and asynchronous read and write
>   operations.

EDIT: You can set an application to require elevated trust by setting the "Require elevated trust when running outside the browser" in your Silverlight project settings.

Comment: How to what, set the app to require elevated trust?  See my edits.