# security exception when I try to create filestream

Tags: c#, silverlight, filestream

I've got a security exception when I try to create filestream

```
FileStream f = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
```

Even when I set filename as D:\filename.xml(even not on disc C:).

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably Silverlight application hasn't access to disk D for writing. Typically SL application runs in partial trust. You can try to use required elevated trust.

There is similar question - [Silverlight 4.0 FileStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406216/silverlight-4-0-filestream)

Answer (score 1):

If you're building an Out-of-browser Silverlight application, go to your Project Properties and check "Enable running application out of browser".

Inside "Out-of-browser settings" check "Require elevated trust when running outside the browser".

Also, make sure the user running the application has permission to create/write to the destination path.